# if-else cannot type check in Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am writing an API in Typescript, but I got the error `Property 'password' does not exist on type 'unknown'` despite the `if` check.

P.S. the type for `request.body` is `unknown`

```
  login: async (request: FastifyRequest, reply: FastifyReply) => {
    if(!request.body){
      reply.code(400).send({
        message: "Missing request body"
      })
      return
    }

    const { username, password } = request.body

    if(!username || !password){
      reply.code(400).send({
        message: "Missing username or password"
      })
      return
    }
```

How can I type check this correctly? I can already catch the case where `request.body === undefined`, is this an issue of Typescript?

Comment: what's the type of FastifyRequest ? Please update your question with it.

Comment: @NicolaeMaties according to the error message, it's `unknown`.

Comment: @VLAZ, its `unkwown` is `request.body`, not `request.

Comment: @ShivamSingla oops, you're right.

Comment: I have just updated the type in my question

Comment: if `request.body` is unknown, typecast it to some `Record` or your custom `interface`/`type`. For example- `const { username, password } = request.body as Record<string, string>`

Comment: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=24&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAYghgZ2ASwGYgEoQI4FcJJQC8UA3gFBRVQBGA9gCYgD8AXFLgHYDWndA7p3IBfcqEixEKdFjAAbEMTKVqAY0YR2AClXtOuALY0IAJwCUxAHxQ4nRQHp7UVQAtbAc2jiCUF6Ygi5JSIIJyqUFomOPhI7PBIaJjRBMAANFBR8iBxUomyChZE1hTUUGhaAIRReCkAdPRMZiWlGRBZteoMEFoALAAMfWa1CBCcDFrNLVAGBAhwnuwARACyyAgIyJzurTWEDSCLKqXCZkfUUcC4JkLHQaXqnISkHCPXcDPpYIgI-HQmDFBhEpqjFgPVGIpEFAsOp-gAeJAmTbudKI5GWO7UcoVXCvTjvaAAH0JUAqX3Wv3+TTOVEyCg6Gl6AyGIzGExp1Bm63mmigKzWGy2L1M+JmUD+UHJPz+DEOUxOHIuVxu1FEwiAA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the documentation on how to specify the body type (and the expected query parameters, and so on) in Fastify: https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/TypeScript/#request

You'll need to pass parameters to the FastifyRequest generic type, like so:

```js
async (request: FastifyRequest<{
  Body: {
    username: string,
    password: string
  }
}>, reply: FastifyReply)
```